# how to get a reference to function inside the function

Tags: javascript

say i've a function like this

```
function a() {
 //get a reference
 console.log( /*something that will get me reference to function a*/);
}
```

**why?**

I'm thinking so i can do this...

```
function Car() {
   //{reference2myself}.prototype = Vechile.prototype;
   Car.prototype = Vechile.prototype;
}
```

**Note, i've to manually set the Car reference, i dont want to do that**

also, btw, why isn't prototype set inside the main factory function, i understand it'd mean for every instance created off that function all prototype props would be reassigned to the same thing.

What i really wanted to make:

```
Object.prototype.extend = function(clas) {
   clas.call(this);
   this.prototype = this.prototype || {};
   Object.setPrototypeOf(this.prototype, clas.prototype);
   this.prototype.constructor = arguments.caller;
}

//then i could use it like this

function Vechile(){
 this.loc=0;
}

Vechile.prototype.move = function(){
  this.loc++;
};

function Van(){
 this.extend(Vechile);
}
Van.prototype.pickUp = function(){};

var a = new Van();
    // now a should have pickup method
    // move method
    // and Van prototype should be and object which should have its __proto__ set to Car.prototype
```

## UPDATE

I think i've finally figure out the code that lets me simulate class inheritance easily. Please let me know if i'm missing something.

```
Object.prototype.extends = function(clas) {
   clas.call(this);
   var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
   Object.setPrototypeOf(proto, clas.prototype);
}

//then i could use it like this
//super class
function Vechile(){
 this.loc=0;
}

Vechile.prototype.move = function(){
  this.loc++;
};

//sub class
function Van(){
  this.extends(Vechile);
}

Van.prototype.pickUp = function(){};

var a = new Van();
```

Comment: `Car.prototype = ...` ; use function names to refer to them inside the function, or `arguments.callee`, but that's getting frowned upon, so use names. if you want to refer to the object produced by a constructor (as your naming convention suggests), use `this` to hit the instance itself and to define own properties that are not shared between instances.

Comment: Your question as written makes little sense so it would likely clear things up if you explain what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: please check it out now

Comment: using name wont work with extend function that would be sorta helper function

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: don't.

The Car function is a constructor. As a result, it will inherit the prototype properties. You do not want to put `Car.prototype = whatever` *inside* the constructor but rather *outside*.

```
function Car() {
    // foo
}
Car.prototype = Vehicle.prototype;
```

edit:

If your intention is have Car as a subclass of Vehicle:

```
function Car() {
    Vehicle.call(this);
    // this.parent = Vehicle or whatever you want to do
}
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
Car.prototype.constructor = Vehicle;
```

Comment: i was trying to make a extend/super function for javascript which will do two things. When invoked inside constructor it will run parent contructor on this and then set prototype object that inherits from parent constructor's prototype

Comment: @MuhammedUmer If you are trying to call the parent, then you must call it directly. Unfortunately in ES5, there isn't a prettier way to do this. See edit.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I see what you are trying to do, using a helper function of sorts to subclass, but like I said before: unfortunately, with the current version of JS, such method will cause side effects and is considered to be the "wrong" way to inherit. Take a look at some arbitary [Three.js source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/Camera.js), which uses the method in this answer as well.

Comment: can you check new extends method. I can't think of any side effect beside it being global function

Comment: and that it's ie11+ only thing